# Why does blender get laggy after an action, but fixes itself immediately after clicking out and back in?

Tags: 3d-view, performance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz0Ji.jpg

As you can see in this video, it acts so laggy after doing an action, any action, but it fixes itself immediately after if i simply click out then back in.

I tried restarting my laptop and that didn't do anything. I have a predator Helios 300 and Blender runs great on it, this is a new issue I've never experienced before. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with memory!?! It looks as if Blender first works with RAM and then for some reason it is forced to work with memory swapped to disk. It would be nice to see the memory monitor of your OS at the same time.

Comment: thank you for replying, i am not very technologically literate so forgive me if this is incorrect but this is what i see in my task manager https://imgur.com/a/Clht7Fa

Comment: Just to rule this completely out, can you provide a video just like the one you made in your question with blender and the task manger side by side? This way it is easier to see if there is a memory event, the moment you run into the problem. 
Looking at your memory in the screenshot it does not seem to be the reason though...

Comment: Another idea is to share the .blend file, in order to see if the problem is just on your system or if the cause is somewhere in the .blend itself.

Comment: this happens with every file so im assuming its computer related. here is the video, sorry that its not great lol i hope it gets the point across https://imgur.com/a/t3yWHzz

Comment: here is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=4vkmyOlQ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/4vkmyOlQ/)

Comment: From what I can tell, the video shows at least that there seems to be no swapping to disk happen, when the effect occurs.
What bothers me is your WIFI graph. It seems as if the effect occurs whenerver there is a spike in your WIFI. Can you disable WIFI and see if this changes anything?

Comment: Your blend file does indeed work on my system flawlessly.

Comment: i tried turning off my internet, and i still experience the same issue

Comment: OK, sorry if I seem a little bit pedantic, but I think it is important to be precise at these things: Did you turn off Internet or did you disable WIFI? Meaning: is the WiFi graph in the task manager now silent?
The other thing is, that it would be good to know what task is causing the regular spikes on the WIFI. Maybe this task is still running and disrupting your blender in some way. Did you install any new software recently?

Comment: i mean, i disconnected and turned on airplane mode, and in task manager it completely disappears so i believe so. i didnt install anything new recently, no.

Comment: i may have figured out the issue, it stopped happening after i closed out photoshop. do you know why photoshop could have been causing such an issue?

Comment: @jasmine Please add additional information into your original post, don't post it as comments where it can easily be missed

Comment: @jasmine sometimes, when photoshop is not closed, it consumes a lot of memory. I've experienced it myself :). Photoshop constantly stores its temporary cache in the memory, camming it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having photoshop open was causing the issue, closing it fixed the issue.